# PHP: foreach - reverse 1 iteration

Tags: php

Let's say I've a code:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    //do something
    if($var === true) //"reverse"
}
```

is it possible to "reverse" foreach, so it'll "run" with the same array's element it was "running" when called to "get back" ;)?

Comment: where is `$var` coming from? and reverse starting from where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use a normal `for` loop and make the last parameter (the modifying part) depend on a variable.

Expr3 in the following manual entry: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: I was hoping this can be ommited.

Answer (score 2):

Not with a `foreach`, no.  You could do this:

```
$array = range(1,10);

for (
    $dir = 1, reset($array); 
    $val = current($array); // for keys, use list($key,$val) = each($array)
    $dir == 1 ? next($array) : prev($array)
) {
    echo "{$val}\n";
    if ($val == 7) {
        $dir = -1;
    }
}
```